# Change matplotlib grid color with rcParams

Tags: python, matplotlib

How is this done? `mpl.rcParams['grid.color']` doesn't work.

Default is white:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

plt.plot([1, 2])
```

[image: original plot, white grid]

And changing with `plt.grid` works fine:

```
plt.plot([1, 2])
plt.grid(c='black')
```

[image: black grid]

But not `rcParams`:

```
mpl.rcParams['grid.color'] = 'black'
plt.plot([1, 2])
```

[image: still white grid]

Comment: Default is no grid, and not white grid ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would first want to set the grid on, then determine its color

```
mpl.rcParams.update({"axes.grid" : True, "grid.color": "black"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `plt.grid()` in your second example.

Like this :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

plt.plot([1, 2])
mpl.rcParams['grid.color'] = 'black'
plt.grid()
```

[image]

And further idea:
You can also try to use seaborn, it is build on top of matplotlib and has really nice formatations:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

plt.plot([1, 2])
```

[image]